# Android Layout for Google Maps - Choose starting point Screen

Tags: android, android-layout

Please have a look at this screenshot from Google Maps for Android. What layout is Google using for this particular screen?

Using multiple ListView controls here would be an overkill in terms of performance (or so I think). Also, because one can scroll on this screen, I don't think Google is using ListView controls here as ListView controls don't work along with ScrollView controls. Is Google using multiple instances of the all new CardView control on top of a ScrollView control here?

Can someone help with the best possible layout (from a performance perspective) for rendering this particular screen? I need to make sure my app supports lower end Android handsets so rendering performance is the number one priority but nothing like achieving it with clean, simple & reusable code + layouts (if possible in this scenario).

Thanks in advance!

[image: Google Maps for Android]

Comment: I believe that layout is achieved with CardView. Scroll down to see some examples https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html